# set azuresqlserveractivedirecoty admin to ADgroup in azure sqlsever using azure powershell inline task in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-powershell, paas

I am trying to execute below command in azure devops to set the AD group as setsqlserveradmin.

```
Set-AzSqlServerActiveDirectoryAdministrator -ResourceGroupName "xyz" -ServerName "xyzsqlserver" -DisplayName "ADgroup" -ObjectId "27f75d8c-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"
```

Below is the Error logs

```
2020-05-07T15:55:05.2211587Z ##[command]Disconnect-AzAccount -Scope Process 
    ErrorAction Stop 2020-05-07T15:55:05.6167436Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope Process - ErrorAction 
    Stop 2020-05-07T15:55:05.9479005Z ##[error]Cannot find the Azure Active Directory object 'Adgroup'. 
    Please make sure that the user or group you are authorizing is registered in the current 
    subscription's Azure Active directory. To get a list of Azure Active Directory groups use Get- 
    AzADGroup, or to get a list of Azure Active Directory users use Get-AzADUser. 2020-05- 
    07T15:55:06.0117846Z ##[section]Finishing: Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript
```

Note - I checked Adgroup and correponding objectid is correct.

powershell task 4.0 and version 3.1.0

[image]

Comment: Did you check the Azure AD group existence in the same context and thus subscription used by the ARM service connection of the failing script?

Comment: Hi Alfredo, I checked AD group is present in the Active directory section with the same name that I am passing in Display name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, first, make sure the group is in the same tenant of your service connection.

[image]

Then navigate to the Azure portal -> `Azure Active Directory` -> `App registrations` -> find the AD App Registration related to your service connection, follow the steps below to add the *Application permission* `Directory.Read.All` of `Azure Active Directory Graph`(not `Microsoft Graph`), don't forget to click the **`Grant admin consent for xxx`** button at last.

[image]

[image]

[image]

After adding the permission, there is some delay(30m - 1h), then test the command, it works.

[image]